# How to override a project deployment in jBPM

Tags: java, jbpm, kie

I want to override my old deployment but I can not do it.
I am using jBPM 6.5.0.Final.
I can deploy my project for the first time without problems. But if, for example, I make some changes on my project and want to deploy it again it fails and shows this error:

```
Deployment of unit testUni:testingProject:1.0 failed: unit already deployed! (override deployment: false)
```

PS: when I click on Build & Deploy, it asks me if I want to Override, and of course I choose to Override.

[image]

But it doesn't override it. I know that the problem is in a configuration file,  but I still can't find in which one.

What I am doing now is to undeploy at each time my deployment and deploy again, but I need a permanent solution.

I know that by adding the option `-Dorg.kie.override.deploy.enabled=true` when launching the server using `standalone.bat` it will work, but I need to configure it permanently.

can anyone help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/jbpm-usage/LGCGOwknEBA/4Ove2zEZAgAJ) after asking the same question in this group (unfortunately no one is answering on stackoverflow ..), I repost it here if someone faces the same issue in the future and come here..

**the answer:**
You can define this (`org.kie.override.deploy.enabled=true`) in standalone-full.xml of wildfly and that will be permanent solution and would eliminate any need to pass this as part of standalone.bat command
   
 code to add:

```
<system-properties>
       <property name="org.kie.override.deploy.enabled" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```